# How to set multiple arguments with pyarg_parsetuple in C?

Tags: python, c

How can I setup the `PyArg_ParseTuple` function with more than one argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example:

```
const char *field = 0; PyObject *value; int typeField; size_t size = 0;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "isO|n", &typeField, &field, &value, &size)) {
  return 0;
}
```

The characters in the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument have to correspond to the C types of the passed pointers, of course.

Btw. the `size` is an optional parameter.

A complete doc. about `PyArg_ParseTuple()` can be found in the Python doc.

[Parsing arguments and building values](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html).

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to get all arguments

```
  vector<PyObject*> objects;
  int argc = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args);
  objects.resize(argc);

  for (int i=0; i<argc ; i++) {
    objects[i] = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, i);
  }
```